# Why does one of my columns not show when I try to implement it in the Select statement

Tags: postgresql

The problem is that one of my columns is not showing and I get this error message

> MISSING FORM clause entry for table \r\

I tried this

```
SELECT MAX(amount) AS amount FROM (SELECT starttime, COUNT(playlistitemid) AS amount FROM radiobroadcast LEFT JOIN playlistitem USING (radiobroadcastid) GROUP BY starttime) r
```

and with this only the table amount is shown Then I tried this

```
SELECT r.starttime, MAX(amount) AS amount FROM (SELECT starttime, COUNT(playlistitemid) AS amount FROM radiobroadcast LEFT JOIN playlistitem USING (radiobroadcastid) GROUP BY r.starttime) r
```

And then I got the error message

So could you please explain why it is not working?

Comment: 1) This 'MISSING FORM clause entry for table \r\' is not the actual error message. Please  update the question with the correct error message. 2) This `GROUP BY r.starttime` should be `GROUP BY starttime`. The `r` alias exists outside the sub query.

Comment: What is your query supposed to do?

Comment: try change GROUP BY r.starttime to `GROUP BY 1`.